# Import module in javascript

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I am currently trying to use a function to export a html table to an excel file. The problem is whenever i try to call the modules needed it returns an error

Here's the code:

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx'

function CalculateMedia(){

    const wb = XLSX.readFile('C:/Users/pedro/Downloads/WebsiteFinal/assets/ExcelTemplate.xlsx');
    const ws = wb.Sheets['Folha1'];

    ws['B1'] = { t: 'n', v: pt10 };
    ws['C2'] = { t: 'n', v: pt11 };
    ws['D3'] = { t: 'n', v: pt12 };

    const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

    const blob = new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'result.xlsx';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    setTimeout(function () {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }, 0);

}

function s2ab(s) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
    }
    return buf;
}
```

**Error:**
[image: error]

Also tried to use `const XLSX = require('xlsx');` but is says require is not defined

Comment: The script tag loading this code needs `type="module"` attribute.

Comment: @Teemu but what if this is not actually a script? I used npm install to add the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

try to move your import inside the CalculateMedia function

Comment: I tried to but i won't let me. When I do it the following error pops up:
"An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module.ts(1473)"

Comment: do you trying to use this for web ?

Comment: yes I am, but I have figured a way to solve this issue.

Comment: so add your solution here for others

Comment: the solution i opted for was using a different function that does the same thing but without the import statement as I am using a different library. So my solution won’t solve the problem I asked for but the function itself. Do you still want me to add the new function?